Pine Script Backtester Misinterprets strategy.order Scaling as Separate Trades
I'm developing a Pine Script strategy on TradingView with scaling entries positions.
While strategy.order should ideally scale into an existing position, the backtester seems to interpret each strategy.order call as a separate trade, leading to inaccurate backtesting results.
According to the pine script manual strategy.order does have the ability to scale into open orders.
I have tried using strategy.entry (which does not have this ability) with pyramiding enabled, but got the same problem with the backtester recognizing them as separate trades.
Expected Behavior:
I expect the backtester to recognize the strategy.order calls as increasing the size of the initial  position, not creating separate trades.
Question:
How can I modify my code to ensure the backtester correctly interprets the scaling behavior of strategy.order ?
The code is as follows:
            if (shortCounter == 1) //initial order

                strategy.order("Short", strategy.short, qty=position_size1, comment="Short 1")

            else if (shortCounter == 2) // subsequent scaling in points

                strategy.order("Short", strategy.short, qty=position_size2, comment="Scaled in Short 2")

            else if (shortCounter == 3)

                strategy.order("Short", strategy.short, qty=position_size3, comment="Scaled in Short 3")



pyramiding only controls how many trades you can start in one direction. It usually puts up a guardrail so bad programs don't run amok.
I wonder, what is the difference between sizing an existing position or starting a new trade? You will be exposed the same amount in both cases.

With strategy.entry & pyramiding you can have multiple entries
With switch you can have multiple positionSize
Try this:
float positionSize = na
switch
    shortCounter == 1 ? positionSize := position_size1
    shortCounter == 2 ? positionSize := position_size2
    shortCounter == 3 ? positionSize := position_size3

shortCondition = shortCounter != shortCounter[1]

if shortCondition
    strategy.entry(
      'Short',
      strategy.short,
      qty = positionSize,
      comment = "Short")


Thank you for your help, I made a similar structure and also consolidated the code; I used in total two strategy.order functions.
An initial strategy.order for the initial trigger, and after the scalilng in trigger a secondary strategy.order, now the strategy.order scales in as intended, the backtester still counts and displays each scaling in point with a seperate number but the contracts size of the scaling in points are added on top of the initial order, so the scaling in works as intended.
